# can network Redundancy possible with help of Layer 2 switches & dual NIC in one PC & program in java?

Tags: networking, java, switch

I am Trying to achieve Network Redundancy in network which have 1 server & lots of node which use 1 switch for each.
As per various forums for achieve Redundancy in network i should use Layer 3 switch.
But i think one possibility (may its wrong)
Test scenario:-
As server there are 2 NIC cards.
From eth0 ie NIC 1's wire goes to Main Switch from Main Switch wire goes to Node1's Switch & as Daisy Chain its going on till last Node's Switch.
From Last Node Switch wire comes to complete Redundancy to eth1 ie NIC 2 in server.

Can anybody tell me whether this thought really work in same network means all ip within 10.111.17.0 to 10.111.17.254
Or I have to write program which maintain ip address & check its connectivity. If one node fails to communicate with server's 1 NIC then that java program send request from different NIC which have different network address '10.111.18.xxx'. I can keep program in each node so they can change their own ip as per NIC response.(These program is also theoretical right now if i got reply yes then i try to find out how to write these program)
By this way i can achieve Redundancy in my Network & can use Layer 2 switches so cost also less.

Any suggestion/idea/clue regarding this thought?

Comment: Describe what the java program is supposed to be doing, and what the roles of the server and nodes are.

Comment: Also, is this on a LAN, or over WAN links?

Comment: java program will in server maintain ip address & send packet (ping) them via NIC 1 & if packet fail then send packet through NIC 2. On Nodes java program Send & Receive packet from Server NIC 1's network if packet fail it change its node ip for NIC 2 network. Whole thought for LAN.

Comment: But *what does the program do*? Why are you writing it? What value does it add to the business?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you're trying to reinvent NIC teaming at Layer 3, which is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need L3 switches to add resilience, it's almost irrelevant - what you need is dual NICs, ideally using different processors and drivers - and team them within the OS.

Then connect one to one switch and the other to a second switch, these can be L2 switches easily, so long as you're using Active/Passive and both switches connect to one or more routers - actually even without dual routers you'd have added a great deal of resilience by just doing what I said. IP is pretty irrelevant here too by the way.

Comment: Thanks for answering...At server i have 2 NIC & 1 Main switch as each node 1 switch, So NIC 1 on 1 network & NIC 2 on another, as per my idea. I not understand about different processor & driver, Can you elaborate your idea? Can i achieve it within one network?

Comment: There's a chance you're in the wrong place - have your read our help pages about what and who we're here for?